# ImportError: cannot import name 'sftp_operator' from 'airflow.providers.sftp.operators

Tags: python, airflow

I created new connection in `Connection` tab and called it as *sftp_test* and conn type as `SFTP`.
I've also created new `dag` presented below nevertheless getting such error on the `gui`. Any thoughts?

**Error:**

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/sftp_test.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/sftp_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.sftp.operators import sftp_operator
ImportError: cannot import name 'sftp_operator' from 'airflow.providers.sftp.operators' (/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/sftp/operators/__init__.py)
```

**Dag:**

```
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators import sftp_operator
from airflow import DAG
import datetime

dag = DAG(
'sftp_test',
start_date = datetime.datetime(2020,1,8,0,0,0),
schedule_interval = '* * * * *'
)

put_operation = SFTPOperator(
            task_id="operation",
            ssh_conn_id="sftp_test",
            local_filepath="/test.txt",
            remote_filepath="/test.txt",
            operation="put",
            dag=dag
            )

put_operation
```

Answer (score 1):

Your import is incorrect:

```
from airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp import SFTPOperator
```

See the [documentation page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/_api/airflow/providers/sftp/operators/sftp/index.html#airflow.providers.sftp.operators.sftp.SFTPOperator) for the provider for the correct path to the `SFTPOperator`.